# Do deleted commits on my local branch also get pushed to my remote repo with git?

Tags: git, version-control

I have done a couple of commits on my branch and then I've decided to get rid of them using git-reset. I made a couple more commits on this branch. I've never pushed anything related to this branch to my remote repo. If I push my changes at this point, will any of these deleted commits get also pushed (although not directly associated with this branch), or the only pushed stuff is what's currently relevant to this branch right now (HEAD and everything it directly or transitively points to?)

Another way of asking this is (although this was not the case): if I accidentally commit my password, and then remove it with git-reset from the given branch, and only then push, should I still have security concerns about it being available for others to see on the remote repo, or am I ok?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have done a couple of commits on my branch and then I've decided to get rid of them using git-reset
>
> ...
>
> I've never pushed anything related to this branch to my remote repo. If I push my changes at this point, will any of these deleted commits get also pushed

Nope. All the work in git is done locally **until** the point when you push and then you are sharing your work with the rest of the world.

Your deleted commits are **still** in your local repo and can be recovered if needed but they are not pushed in any way to remote.

---

### ***`How to get list of my deleted commits?`***

```
# get list of the "loose" object (aka dangling) content.
git fsck --full
```

Now you can use the `git cat-file -p` to display the content and recover it if you will even need it again.